# Two outputs for one DataSource

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to process log files and save almost similar results to two different places without needing to process the whole log files all over again.

e.g.

```
    ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataSource<Integer> ds = env.fromCollection(bigData());


    MapOperator<Integer, Integer> hardWorkDS = ds.map(i -> {

        System.out.println("enter hard work");

        return hardWork(i);
    });


    saveToDB(hardWorkDS.collect());
    saveToAnotherDB(hardWorkDS.map(i -> moreWork(i)).collect());
```

this code prints "enter hard work" twice the number of elements in the data source.
I know this is how it's supposed to work, as "collect()" evaluates the whole data from the start with each call.

Is there a workaround I can do in order to not process the same data twice?

I know it's possible in streaming, but I cannot use streaming for this one.

Answer (score 2):

A DataSet program can have as many data sinks as you need. Just add one ore more sinks with `DataSet.output(OutputFormat)` and call `env.execute()` to start the program. Flink provides a `JDBCOutputFormat` which you might use to write data into a database.

As you noticed, you should not use `collect()` because it immediately executes the program. Besides preventing multiple data sinks `collect()` has the drawback that it fetches the data into the client before writing it to the database. Writing data directly from the `OutputFormat` is a more scalable solution.